# в случае нахождения NOK выводит 0, что не так?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;


int main() {
    
    long a, b, NOD, NOK;

    cout << "enter a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter b: ";
    cin >> b;

    

    while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
        if (a > b)
            a = a - b;
        else
            b = b - a;
    }


    NOD = a + b;

    NOK = (a * b) / NOD;
    

    cout << "NOD of numbers: " << NOD << endl;
    cout << "NOK of numbers: " << NOK << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да хотя бы потому, что из цикла вы выходите когда? Когда либо `a`, либо `b` становится равным 0. Т.е. `a*b` равно 0.

Все понятно?

Только вот так считать НОД (кстати, по-английски НОД и НОК —  GCD и LCM) как минимум страшно неэффективно (не считая того, что эти функции уже есть в стандартной библиотеке)...

```
long gcd(T m, T n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}

long lcm(T m, T n)
{
    return (m/gcd(m,n))*n;
}
```

Так куда эффективнее. И обратите внимание, что у меня НОК вычисляется как

```
(m/gcd(m,n))*n
```

в то время как у вас

```
(m*n)/gcd(m,n)
```

В чем разница и почему лучше так, как у меня — подумайте сами.

Comment: А как тогда можно изменить именно мою запись нахождения НОД? Желательно без подключения библиотеки и без добавления функций.

Comment: Добавить две переменные — копии `a` и `b`, с которыми и работать..

Comment: спасибо большое)